# How to create another version or re-package my application in Eclipse

Tags: android

I want to create a free version of my application which will be limited in features and have notifications and links to get the full version.

I can create another copy of the entire project on the hard drive but the package path needs to change in all .java files and manifest. Do I do this manually or is there a better way in Eclipse to organise different versions of an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [new Library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) and put all common code in it.

Then create two Android projects (one free on payable) that reference the library project.